# error TS6059: ' is not under 'rootDir', 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: angular, deployment, monorepo, nomachine-nx

I'm experiencing issues with deploying an application I'm working on with Angular and NX. The issue I'm facing is that I don't quite grasp how the application should be configured to avoid this error. At the root of the entire project, I have:

Project Root:

```
|-- apps
|   |-- app ngshop
|   |-- app admin

|-- environments

|-- libs
|   |-- orders
|   |-- products
|   |-- ui
|   |   |-- src
|   |   tsconfig.json

|-- nx.json
|-- tsconfig.base
```

So, it seems like I'm unable to access the files from the libraries when I try to deploy the admin or ngshop app.

Here is the 'nx.json' configuration:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
    "npmScope": "bluebits",
    "affected": {
      "defaultBase": "master"
    },
    "cli": {
      "packageManager": "npm"
    },
    "tasksRunnerOptions": {
      "default": {
        "runner": "nx-cloud",
        "options": {
          "cacheableOperations": [
            "build",
            "lint",
            "test",
            "e2e"
          ],
          "accessToken": "ZTEyOGYxNjMtZjM4Mi00YzQ0LTk1N2MtYzJiMGY5NzYxZDIxfHJlYWQtd3JpdGU="
        }
      }
    },
    "targetDefaults": {
      "build": {
        "dependsOn": [
          "^build"
        ],
        "inputs": [
          "production",
          "^production"
        ]
      },
      "pluginsConfig": {
        
      },
      "lint": {
        "inputs": [
          "default",
          "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintrc.json"
        ]
      },
      "e2e": {
        "inputs": [
          "default",
          "^production"
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "inputs": [
          "default",
          "^production",
          "{workspaceRoot}/jest.preset.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    "generators": {
      "@nx/angular:application": {
        "style": "scss",
        "linter": "eslint",
        "unitTestRunner": "jest",
        "e2eTestRunner": "cypress"
      },
      "@nx/angular:library": {
        "linter": "eslint",
        "unitTestRunner": "jest"
      },
      "@nx/angular:component": {
        "style": "scss"
      }
    },
    "defaultProject": "ngshop",
    "namedInputs": {
      "default": [
        "{projectRoot}/**/*",
        "sharedGlobals"
      ],
      "sharedGlobals": [],
      "production": [
        "default",
        "!{projectRoot}/.eslintrc.json",
        "!{projectRoot}/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)?(.snap)",
        "!{projectRoot}/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "!{projectRoot}/jest.config.[jt]s",
        "!{projectRoot}/src/test-setup.[jt]s"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Here is the 'tsconfig.base' configuration:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@bluebits/orders": ["libs/orders/src/index.ts"], 
      "@bluebits/products": ["libs/products/src/index.ts"],
      "@bluebits/ui": ["libs/ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@bluebits/uiBanner": ["libs/ui/src/lib/components/banner/banner.component.ts"],
      "@bluebits/users": ["libs/users/src/index.ts"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

And here is the 'tsconfig.json' configuration for the UI library, for example:

```
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

The issue started with environment variables, as I was getting an error stating that they should be inside each library. What I did was make a copy of the file and put it inside each lib. I know it's not the best practice, but I couldn't find another solution. However, now I'm encountering the same error with other modules from the UI libraries:

`>  NX   libs/ui/src/lib/Components/banner/banner.component.ts:1:1 - error TS6059: File 'C:/Users/Ale/Desktop/EC-eshop-FrontEnd/bluebits/libs/ui/src/lib/Components/banner/banner.component.ngtypecheck.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\Users\Ale\Desktop\EC-eshop-FrontEnd\bluebits\libs\products\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

And like this one, I have several more errors of the same type.

Finally, I want to emphasize that any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.